# which method does catboost use to choose the best variables to build the tree?

Tags: catboost

In this article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.09516.pdf, they explain how Catboost choose the best split to build the tree ( with cosine of similitude if I understood correctly ) but nowhere can I find which method the algorithm uses to choose the variables on which it will build the tree?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can find the answer in their [documentation](https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/algorithm-main-stages_choose-tree-structure.html):
"This is a greedy method. Features are selected in order along with their splits for substitution in each leaf. Candidates are selected based on data from the [preliminary calculation of splits](https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/algorithm-main-stages_pre-count.html#algorithm-main-stages_pre-count) and the [transformation of categorical features to numerical features](https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/algorithm-main-stages_cat-to-numberic.html#algorithm-main-stages_cat-to-numberic)."